# Doctrine 2.1 reference table

Tags: php, annotations, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I have a reference table album_content which has: `album_id`, `content_id`, and `sort_key`. I set it up as an entity with @ManyToOne relations:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *  @JoinColumn(name="album_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $albumId;

/**
* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Content")
* @JoinColumns({
*  @JoinColumn(name="content_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* })
*/
private $contentId;

/**
* @Column(name="sort_key", type="integer", nullable=false)
*/
private $sortKey;
```

Right now Doctrine is complaining `No identifier/primary key specified`. What's the correct annotation to reference these without adding an extra ID column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably shouldn't be naming things $contentId or $albumId, but instead just call them $content and $album.

That said, the quick solution is to add @Id annotations to both of your associations.

The manual goes into further detail about using [composite keys in Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata).